# Cannot create functioning subclass in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, subclass, attributeerror

I am having trouble getting a subclass to behave properly. When instantiating the superclass, everything works as expected. But the getters and setters in the subclass don't seem to do anything.

Commenting out the call to the superclass `__init__` function has no effect, its as if its not even there.

```
class Animal:
    __name = None
    __sound = 0

    def __init__(self, name, sound):
        self.__name = name
        self.__sound = sound

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_sound(self):
        return self.__sound

    def get_type(self):
        return "Animal"

    def toString(self):
        return "{} says {}".format(self.__name, self.__sound)

class Dog(Animal):
    __owner = None

    def __init__(self, name, sound, owner):
        super().__init__(name, sound)
        self.__owner = owner    

    def set_owner(self, owner):
        self.__owner = owner

    def get_owner(self):
        return self.__owner

    def get_type(self):
        return "Dog"

    def toString(self):
        return "{} says {} and his owner is {}".format(self.__name, self.__sound, self.__owner)

cat = Animal('Whiskers', 'Meow')
print(cat.toString())

spot = Dog("Spot", "Borf!", "Derek")
spot.set_name = "Spot?"
spot.set_owner = "Brad"
print(spot.get_type())
print(spot.get_name())
print(spot.get_owner())
print(spot.toString())
print(spot.multiple_sounds(howmany=4))
```

The given output comes out as:

```
Whiskers says Meow
Dog
Spot
Derek
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hellopython.py", line 245, in <module>
    print(spot.toString())
  File "./hellopython.py", line 228, in toString
    return "{} says {} and his owner is {}".format(self.__name, self.__sound, self.__owner)
    AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute '_Dog__name'
```

Which I don't understand, as I am expecting the name and owner to be changed. Why can't anything be gotten or set outside of the superclass init function? I am using python 3, other posts on this topic have suggested putting arguments in the class to super (python 2 only, tried it and still doesn't work). Why are the attributes not accessible in this context?

Comment: Why did you *specifically turn on this behavior* by using leading double underscores if you didn't want it?

Comment: Also, whatever resource you're learning from was clearly written with another language in mind, probably Java, and then crudely converted to Python without much regard for the difference between the languages. For example, those `toString` methods, and the class-level variables that just get shadowed by instance variables (assuming those were something your class or book or whatever said to put in). You can find something better.

Comment: Thank you user2357112, I didn't realize that double underscores caused this behavior when sub classing but it makes sense now that I think about it. Funny how it didn't seem to cause anything in what I was following along on though.